# Import github project into preexisting git project

Tags: git

[image]

I'm working on a flask app in a local git repo. I've come across a python script that I would like to import into my project root from github. I'm not sure how to "pull in/import" this script into my local repo, without affecting my pre-existing code. Can someone advise me here. Is it as simple as

```
git clone https://github.com/xxx/yyy.git
```

( I don't want to try for fear of messing up my local repo )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an additional remote branch to your repo:

`git remote add <yyy> https://github.com/xxx/yyy.git`

Once that's done, you can pull directly from your new remote with:

`git pull <yyy> master`

This will automatically attempt to merge the code from the remote repo into your local repo.